# Select sub_Dataframe with postive element and return index in sub_List

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe looking like this.

```
                         A        
 2013-01-05 00:00:00     0
 2013-01-05 01:00:00     0
 2013-01-05 02:00:00     5
 2013-01-05 03:00:00     20
 2013-01-05 04:00:00     10
 2013-01-05 05:00:00     0
 2013-01-05 06:00:00     0
 2013-01-05 07:00:00     3
 2013-01-05 07:00:00     6
```

I tried to select sub dataframes with positive values and extract their indexes

```
List= df[df['A']>0].index.tolist()
```

Index of first and last positive element of each sub dataframe, put the sub list in list: for this dataframe  [[5,10],[3,6]] and return their indexes

```
Desired output:List[[ 2013-01-05 02:00:00,2013-01-05 04:00:00],[2013-01-05 07:00:00,2013-01-05 08:00:00]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
idx_list = (
    df
    .assign(
        group=df["A"].gt(0).diff().fillna(False).cumsum(), idx=df.index
    )[df["A"].gt(0)]
    .groupby("group").agg({"idx": lambda col: [col.iat[0], col.iat[-1]]})
    .idx.to_list()
)
```

Result with

```
df = 
                     A
2013-01-05 00:00:00   0
2013-01-05 01:00:00   0
2013-01-05 02:00:00   5
2013-01-05 03:00:00  20
2013-01-05 04:00:00  10
2013-01-05 05:00:00   0
2013-01-05 06:00:00   0
2013-01-05 07:00:00   3
2013-01-05 08:00:00   6
```

is

```
[[Timestamp('2013-01-05 02:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-05 04:00:00')],
 [Timestamp('2013-01-05 07:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-05 08:00:00')]]
```

Comment: @ Timus, thank you for your response, It works well, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Change index for the column name and then extract the first and the last element from a list:

```
my_list = df[df['A']>0]['A'].to_list()
my_list= [my_list[0],my_list[-1]]
```

Comment: @ Pablo Thank you for your response but the desired output  is to extract the index of each sub dataframe (first and last ) which  values are strictly positive. put each first and end index in sublist Sub1=[ 2013-01-05 02:00:00,2013-01-05 04:00:00] and Sub2= [2013-01-05 07:00:00,2013-01-05 08:00:00].             
Final list contains all sublists. e.g. my_list= [Sub1 ,sub2] then my_list= [[ 2013-01-05 02:00:00,2013-01-05 04:00:00],[2013-01-05 07:00:00,2013-01-05 08:00:00]]